# Solve $(n+1)t_{n+1}=(n+2)t_n+1$, $t_1=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, recurrence-relations, alternative-proof

> Solve the recurrence relation
> $$(n+1)t_{n+1}=(n+2)t_n+1,~~~~~~~t_1=1$$

Computing the first few values of the recurrence relation causes us to suspect that the solution is $t_n=n$, which indeed is easily proven by mathematical induction.

However, in the solution that the book that contains this question gives, it begins by stating that
$$(n+1)t_{n+1}=(n+2)t_n+1$$
$$(n+2)t_{n+2}=(n+3)t_{n+1}+1$$
which I understand easily. It then goes on to say that:

> Subtracting, rearranging and letting $u_n=t_{n+1}-t_n$, we obtain $u_{n+1}=u_n$ and so $u_n=1$. Hence $t_n=n$.

I am afraid that I don't understand this solution. Subtracting the simultaneous equations seems to give singularly useless equations which I cannot seem to rearrange to obtain the required relation (the required relation being $t_{n+2}-t_{n+1}=t_{n+1}-t_n$).

Please help me understand the solution's line of reasoning.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Label the two equations A and B. Do (B-A) and cancel (n+2).

Comment: @cosmo5 my difficulty was spotting the common factor $(n+2)$, but thanks to the answer below I see the simple rearrangement; thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(n+2)t_{n+2} = (n+3)t_{n+1}+1$$

$$(n+1)t_{n+1} = (n+2)t_{n}+1$$

Subtracting:

$$(n+2)t_{n+2} - (n+1)t_{n+1} = (n+3)t_{n+1} -(n+2)t_{n}$$

Move one $t_{n+1}$ from RHS to LHS:
$$(n+2)t_{n+2} - (n+2)t_{n+1} = (n+2)t_{n+1} -(n+2)t_{n}$$

Now divide both sides by $n+2$ to obtain
$$t_{n+2}-t_{n+1}=t_{n+1}-t_n$$

Comment: OMG I can't believe I missed such a simple trick...thanks so much :))