# Reccursive formula as a non-recursive

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recursion

The recursive formula is give as follows:

$$ s_n = n s_{n-1} + (n-1)!$$ and $s_2 = 1$. How to construct a non-recursive formula?

Comment: What is $d_2=1$?

Comment: It would help if you at least write the problem statement correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By working out the first few cases, you observe that the sequence satisfies
$$s_n=n!(s_0+H_n)\,,$$ where $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$ is the $n$th harmonic number. One can then confirm that it is indeed the case by observing that $$s_{n+1}=(n+1)s_n+n!=(n+1)!(s_0+H_n)+n!=(n+1)!\left(s_0+H_n+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=(n+1)!(s_0+H_{n+1})\,.$$
You can obtain your particular sequence by substituting the appropriate value for $s_0$.

Comment: $H_n$ is the $n$th *partial sum* of the harmonic series

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it, but I meant to say “number” and not “series”.

Comment: @MariyaKav: $s0$ is the value of the sequence $s_n$ when $n=0$. Since you say $s_2=1$, then that’s equivalent to $$1=2!(s_0+H_2)\,,$$ which means that $s_0=-1$, so the precise sequence you are asking for becomes $$s_n=n!(H_n-1)\,.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! and regarding the previous question?\

Comment: Okay, so I guess you mean how did I obtain the formula $s_n=n!(s_0+H_n)$. As, I said, I checked a few initial cases and observed that that was the formula; that is, $$s_1=1\cdot s_0+0!=1!(s_0+1)\,,$$ $$s_2=2s_1+1!=2(1!(s_0+1)+1!=2!(s_0+1+\frac{1}{2})\,,$$ $$s_3=3s_0+2!=3\left(2!(s_0+ 1+\frac{1}{2})\right)+2!=3!\left(s_0+ 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)$$ $$\ldots$$ In practice, to confirm that indeed that’s the correct formula, one checks by induction, which I did by showing that it holds for $s_{n+1}$. It appears the answer by Yves Daoust derives the expression directly, and it’s helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Dividing by $n!$,

$$\frac{s_n}{n!}=\frac{s_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+\frac1n,$$

which we can write

$$h_n=h_{n-1}+\frac1n.$$

So obviously

$$h_n=H_n+h_0$$ and $$s_n=n!(H_n+h_0)=n!(H_n+s_0).$$

---

Unfortunately, there is no shortcut to computing the Harmonic numbers exactly, so this result is not much better than the initial recursion.

Comment: @MariyaKav: $h_n=h_{n-1}+f(n)\to h_n=\sum f(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

The relation is equivalent to
$$s_{n+1}=(n+1)s_n+n!,~~s_1=1$$
Let
$$s_n=u_n\times n!$$
$$\implies u_{n+1}\times (n+1)!=(n+1)\times u_n\times n!+n!, ~~~~u_1=1$$
$$\implies (n+1)u_{n+1}=(n+1)u_n+1,~~~u_1=1$$
$$u_{n+1}=u_n+\frac{1}{n+1}$$
This is essentially the relation for the harmonic numbers, which don't have any simple closed form.

It'd be SO much easier to solve if we had
$$\implies (n+1)u_{n+1}=(n+2)u_{n+1}+1$$
instead (see [Solve $(n+1)t_{n+1}=(n+2)t_n+1$, $t_1=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3855759/solve-n1t-n1-n2t-n1-t-1-1)):(
Are you sure it's not that, ie are you certain your relation shouldn't be
$$s_{n+1}=(n+2)s_n+n!,~~s_1=1$$